# Always the same warnings while trying to get a basic sse grizzly/jersey server running

Tags: java, jersey, server-sent-events, grizzly

I'm trying to get better at java with a project that i wanted to try with SSE but while trying to implement the examples of jersey they always give the same 'warnings'.

I first tried to research it and found some possible solutions here but no luck. (all pointed to dependency issues) So trying to save time i went to check the github page of jersey to check out some examples. Again no luck they give the same warnings as my initial try. I can't find much about this topic.

my server part looks something like this:

```
final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().register(RouteResource.class);

HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(UriBuilder.fromUri("").host(host).port(port).path(baseUrl).build(),rc);
```

the RouteResource.class (SSE methods) look something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("api/sounds/subscribe/{token}")
@Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
public void getServerSentEvents(@Context SseEventSink sseEventSink, @Context Sse sse, @PathParam("token") String token) {
    sseEventSink.send(sse.newEvent("Welcome !"));
    sse.newBroadcaster().register(sseEventSink);
    sseEventSink.send(sse.newEvent("You are registred !"));
}
```

When opening the index page that includes some javascript to subscribe to the path it throws these:

```
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink class.
at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:168)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:156)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:105)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:156)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:716)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:670)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:441)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2287)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.igdCacheCompute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1163)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$400(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:105)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1157)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:105)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1237)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:558)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:567)
at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.lambda$new$0(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.lambda$new$0(Cache.java:169)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:225)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache.apply(Cache.java:77)
at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:95)
at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:121)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.lambda$getValueProvider$0(DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.java:67)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:50)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:64)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:109)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$SseEventSinkInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:129)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:353)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
implementation=javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink
contracts={javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink}
scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
qualifiers={}
descriptorType=CLASS
descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
metadata=
rank=0
loader=null
proxiable=null
proxyForSameScope=null
analysisName=null
id=126
locatorId=0
identityHashCode=1706636114
reified=false)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:681)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:441)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2287)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.igdCacheCompute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1163)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$400(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:105)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1157)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:105)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1237)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:558)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:567)
at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.lambda$new$0(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.lambda$new$0(Cache.java:169)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:225)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache.apply(Cache.java:77)
at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:95)
at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:121)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.lambda$getValueProvider$0(DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.java:67)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:50)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:64)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:109)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$SseEventSinkInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:129)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:353)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```